# javascript calculator not getting values from form

Tags: javascript, html

The 2 variables in the beginning `num1` and `num2` are not be grabbed from the HTML form in the JavaScript file.
It does work if I assign the value to the input boxes but not when the user changes the value

I'm new to JavaScript and trying to learn so any help would greatly be appreciated

```js
let num1 = document.getElementById("num1-el").value
let num2 = document.getElementById("num2-el").value

let calEl = document.getElementById("cal-el")
let sumEl = document.getElementById("equals-el")
let sum = 0
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn")

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  if (calEl.value === "+") {
    sum = num1 + num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  } else if (calEl.value === "-") {
    sum = num1 - num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  } else if (calEl.value === "*") {
    sum = num1 * num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  } else if (calEl.value === "/") {
    sum = num1 / num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input id="num1-el" type="number" value="<? echo $num1; ?>">
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="cal-el">
      <option value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="*">*</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="num2-el" type="number">
  </div>
  </form>
  <div>
    <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="equals-el">

  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are initializing `num1 = document.getElementById("num1-el").value` at the very beginning (when it's empty), and then never updating it. You have to grab it and `num2` after you click the button.

Also you have to convert them to number, because they are strings `"2"`, not numbers `2`.

`2 + 3 == 5` but `"2" + "3" == "23"`.

```js
let num1;
let num2;

let calEl = document.getElementById("cal-el")
let sumEl = document.getElementById("equals-el")
let sum = 0
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn")

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  
  num1 = +document.getElementById("num1-el").value;
  num2 = +document.getElementById("num2-el").value;
  
  
  if (calEl.value === "+") {
    sum = num1 + num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  } else if (calEl.value === "-") {
    sum = num1 - num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  } else if (calEl.value === "*") {
    sum = num1 * num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  } else if (calEl.value === "/") {
    sum = num1 / num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input id="num1-el" type="number" value="<? echo $num1; ?>">
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="cal-el">
      <option value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="*">*</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="num2-el" type="number">
  </div>
  </form>
  <div>
    <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="equals-el">

  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if i change .value to .valueAsNumber is will take variables as numbers

Comment: Ha, I never knew this. In my defence I am an Angular developer and I never use things like `getElementById` or `.value`. Good to know anyway , thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You must take values from `input` inside the function as a event is needed to take the values (sometimes it is `onchange`, `oninput` ...).

As the initial values of `input` are `null` means it is empty(on load of script and variables are taking that only). But when you use any event they are filled by now and the updated values will be taken into the variables

Also use `Number()` to convert `string` to `number`

```js
let sum = 0
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn")
let calEl = document.getElementById("cal-el")
let sumEl = document.getElementById("equals-el")

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let num1 = document.getElementById("num1-el").value
  let num11 = Number(num1)
  let num2 = document.getElementById("num2-el").value
  let num22 = Number(num2)

  if (calEl.value === "+") {
    sum = num11 + num22
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  } else if (calEl.value === "-") {
    sum = num1 - num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  } else if (calEl.value === "*") {
    sum = num1 * num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  } else if (calEl.value === "/") {
    sum = num1 / num2
    sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
  }

})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input id="num1-el" type="number" value="<? echo $num1; ?>">
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="cal-el">
      <option value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="*">*</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="num2-el" type="number">
  </div>
  </form>
  <div>
    <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="equals-el">

  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `1` + `2` isn't `12` right?

Comment: Yup it is because you do nothing to convert the values into number

Comment: Yes updated the answer @MaikLowrey as OP has not converted the `object` to `number` . So used a appropriate method to sort it out

Comment: A different issue than Q' but added in a edited answer *thumbs up*

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things are wrong here:

1. You want to sample `num1` and `num2` values when you click the submit button and not when the code loaded.
2. Since you're using `input`, the `.value` is a string so you need to cast it to number with `Number()`.
3. Instead of `sumEl.innerHTML +=`, use only `sumEl.innerHTML =`. Otherwise it will just add another element to the answer.
4. Since you have the same code `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`, you can just export it below all of your `if else` - much cleaner code.
5. Use variables only when you use them. If you don't need them in high scope - don't define them there just because you can.

```js
let calEl = document.getElementById("cal-el");
let sumEl = document.getElementById("equals-el");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let sum = 0;
  let num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1-el").value);
  let num2 = Number(document.getElementById("num2-el").value);

  if (calEl.value === "+") {
    sum = num1 + num2
  } else if (calEl.value === "-") {
    sum = num1 - num2
  } else if (calEl.value === "*") {
    sum = num1 * num2
  } else if (calEl.value === "/") {
    sum = num1 / num2
  }

  sumEl.innerHTML = `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`


})
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="num1-el" type="number" value="<? echo $num1; ?>">
  <div>
    <select id="cal-el">
      <option value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="*">*</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="num2-el" type="number">
  </div>
</form>
<div>
  <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
</div>
<div id="equals-el">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend reading something about server/client sided programming to get the difference between languages like Javascript and PHP. A good start might be
[What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming).

---

To address some of the issues with your code:

1. the HTML is invalid, not all elements that are opened are also closed. Consider using a linter or validator
2. `value="<? echo $num1; ?>"` is [php](/questions/tagged/php) syntax, not needed here.
3. The `<form>` is commonly used to progress something, with a custom action. My guess is you can simplify the code by just using the `onClick`:
4. You're getting the `num1-el` and `num2-el` values **before** the button is pressed, lets move that inside the `onClick` so we're sure we have the up-to-date values.
5. Since `. value` returns a string, we'll need to use [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert it to a real number
6. Since you're always doing the `sumEl.innerHTML += ...`, we can move that outside the `if/else` to make it somewhat more readable.

```js
const btn = document.getElementById("submit-btn")
btn.addEventListener("click", function() {

  let num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1-el").value);
  let num2 = Number(document.getElementById("num2-el").value);

  let calEl = document.getElementById("cal-el")
  let sumEl = document.getElementById("equals-el")
  let sum = 0;

  if (calEl.value === "+") {
    sum = num1 + num2;
  } else if (calEl.value === "-") {
    sum = num1 - num2;
  } else if (calEl.value === "*") {
    sum = num1 * num2;
  } else if (calEl.value === "/") {
    sum = num1 / num2;
  }
  
  sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input, select, button {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <input id="num1-el" type="number">
    <select id="cal-el">
        <option value="+">+</option>
        <option value="-">-</option>
        <option value="*">*</option>
        <option value="/">/</option>
    </select>
    <input id="num2-el" type="number">
    <button id="submit-btn">Calculate</button>
    <div id="equals-el">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any value toke from `input`, `textarea`, `select` or other `HTML element` using javascript, by default it data type is string until using [data type casting](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp)  (converted to a new variable and another data type) on this value.
Also, You can use `switch()` instead `if()` statement, to make your code more clear , and more understable.

```js
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submit-btn");
submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  let sum = 0;
  let num1 = Number(document.getElementById("num1-el").value);
  let num2 = Number(document.getElementById("num2-el").value);
  let calEl = document.getElementById("cal-el");
  let sumEl = document.getElementById("equals-el");
  switch(calEl.value){
    case "+": {sum = num1 + num2;break;}
    case "-": {sum = num1 - num2;break;}
    case "*": {sum = num1 * num2;break;}
    case "/": {sum = num1 / num2;break;}
    // If the user didn't select the operator (+,-,* or /) then the defualt operator is '+';
    default:  {sum = num1 + num2;break;}
  }
  sumEl.innerHTML += `<p>The Answer is ${sum}</p>`;
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightskyblue;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input id="num1-el" type="number" value="<? echo $num1; ?>">
  </div>
  <div>
    <select id="cal-el">
      <option value="+">+</option>
      <option value="-">-</option>
      <option value="*">*</option>
      <option value="/">/</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="num2-el" type="number">
  </div>
  </form>
  <div>
    <button id="submit-btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div id="equals-el">

  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```